# What is an informal term for a person who can't do anything right?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, translation, offensive-language

In Russian we have the term "рукожоп". I would translate it as "asshands" which literally means that your hands grow out of your behind and you can't do anything right (or do anything at all).

Example:

> Dad: "Hey son, can you hang up this picture on the wall?"
>
> Son: "No dad, my hands grow out of my behind, I'll probably end up hanging it upside down" (Or "I am a _____" - i.e. *the term I'm looking for*.)

Is there anything similar in English? Is the term "screw up" the one? Or are there any other ones? I want slang specifically, preferably American.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for slang terms or adjectives? Clumsy could be an adjective.

Comment: @Sweet_Cherry no, I want slang specifically, preferably American.

Comment: If you weren't asking for AmE then I might proffer "pillock", "prat", "plonker", "muppet", etc - you're missing out on a lot of great BrE colloquialisms!

Comment: "clot" is another good BrE term for a clumsy person, I've not heard it in the US, though.

Comment: Is the Russia word vulgar? Your translation would be considered vulgar in English (because "ass" is). Are you looking for the English word to match in terms of being vulgar or not?

Comment: You seem to be looking for a noun, but if it were an adjective, [ham-handed](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ham-handed) is possible.

Comment: Neither “all thumbs” nor “klutz” are slang, and neither is specific to American slang.

Comment: @jpmc26 yes, it is vulgar.

Comment: *duffer* (Merriam-Webster) "an incompetent, ineffectual, or clumsy person"

Comment: When a question attracts a long list of answers, that usually means it is subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has one clearly “right” answer. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”, “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Comment: If possible, add more details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage. If this is not possible because you really do have a subjective question, a welcoming place to ask for advice is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

"All thumbs", according to Wiktionary "clumsy, awkward, not dextrous."

"Klutz", according to Wiktionary "a clumsy or stupid person."

Comment: Yeah, "klutz"..

Comment: "All thumbs" is an adjectival phrase, whereas the question asks for a noun ("an informal term for a person"). However, "klutz" is a noun and fits the bill.

Comment: I think I’m offering fair and not unkind criticism when I say that this answer is not American slang per se, as the OP requested, but rather is a more general English idiom and adopted Yiddish.

Comment: A klutz is someone that is clumsy... a klutz would be more likely to drop and break the picture in the process of hanging it not hang it upside down. I don't think this term properly describes what OP is looking for.

Comment: "klutz" fits the question well, which seems to be asking for "physically clumsy" specifically, not incompetent in general like "fuckup".  "klutz" doesn't have much of a connotation of being a bad / useless person in general, for tasks that aren't physical / mechanical.  e.g. a theoretical physicist could be all thumbs, and that's why they're a theoretician who works at a computer and/or blackboard all day instead of an experimental physicist who builds stuff in their lab.

Answer (score 21):

If you’re looking for vulgar slang, “fuckup” is a good option:

> an extremely offensive word for someone who often makes serious mistakes or fails completely

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fuck-up_2

Screw up works too, but it’s not as offensive.

Both of these words are also verbs.

Comment: That seems somewhat judgemental of the person's character.

Comment: @einpoklum I do think that, if I’m understanding Russian culture correctly, asshands can be used as a judgement of character.

Comment: I agree with @einpoklum, I think that "fuckup" or "screwup" is too broad in meaning.  If it was "растяпа" (bumbler,muddler,wally) then maybe, but I understand "рукожоп" as being particularly about lacking in manual skills.

Comment: *fuckup* is good. ***fucktard*** is even better.

Answer (score 14):

[**Incompetent**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/93712?redirectedFrom=incompetent#eid) springs to mind:

> **a.** Of inadequate ability or fitness; not having the requisite capacity or qualification; incapable.
>
> **B.** An incompetent person.

While we have a lot of fun slang terms here, this would be a term you could use either casually or in a slightly more formal setting.

I've also seen "Incompetent" used as an insult ("Are you incompetent, boy?"), so it would work to be more self-deprecating.

Answer (score 11):

"***Butterfingers***" might be a good word considering the context you used regarding the term "asshands". Generally it implies someone inept with their hands, or lacking in manual dexterity.

As a more brusque offensive term, I'd use the word "Fuck-up."

Comment: This is usually used in the sense of dropping things (literally as though your fingers were slippery with butter) rather than generally lacking dexterity though.

Answer (score 8):

A *bumbler* is informal without being vulgar or obscene.

> He can't do anything right.  He is a *bumbler*.

Comment: Tharpa, this isn't a bad start, but it's too short: the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. Can I suggest you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of *bumbler* (linked to the source)? For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 7):

> [schlemiel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/schlemiel)

A person who fouls up everything by incompetence or bad luck. It was [borrowed into English from Yiddish](https://www.etymonline.com/word/schlemiel) which is from a name of a character in a story (1813).

Compare with [schlemazel](https://www.etymonline.com/word/schlemazel). 
Which actually means 'bad luck' (schlim mazel).

The saying goes, in order to tell which is which, is that the person who spills their bowl of soup is the schlemiel, and the person they spill it on is the schlemazel.

Comment: Laverne & Shirley fan? I don't think this is in common enough usage today to be effective. I don't think most people would know what this means.

Comment: @JeffC many Yiddishisms were much more common in the past, especially in the NYC area. But every so often pop culture will revive one of them. Verklempt, meh, putz, spritz. Schlemiel wass definitely made more popular by L&S.

Answer (score 6):

An idiom, that seems somewhat similar to the Russian one, is 
*No dad, i’m all fingers and thumbs, I'll probably end up hanging it upside down.*

> **be all fingers and thumbs**.
>   To be clumsy with one's hands. Primarily heard in UK, Australia. *Tom could never be a surgeon—he's all fingers and thumbs. Can you sew this button on for me? I'm all fingers and thumbs*.
>   - [thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+all+fingers+and+thumbs)

Comment: This is a verbal phrase, whereas the question asks for a noun ("an informal term for a person").

Comment: @Chappo I did not think “an informal term for a person” meant it was limited to nouns, but I guess it would be best if OP edited question to be more specific.

Answer (score 6):

If s/he "can't do anything right" not just in terms of construction and house-work, but more generally, you can call that person a **good-for-nothing**.

[Dictionary definition](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/good-for-nothing):

> **good-for-noth·ing** 
>   (go͝od′fər-nŭth′ĭng)
>
> *noun*: A person of little worth or usefulness.
>   *adjective*: Having little worth; useless.

Comment: Just because someone is too clumsy to hang a picture, doesn't mean they are a good-for-nothing. They might be excellent at mathematics or poetry or managing a company.

Answer (score 3):

**doofus** or less commonly **dufus**. [Same meaning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doofus).

> a stupid, incompetent, or foolish person.

MW notes that the word is slang, and that it's relatively recent (first known use 1960).

Further background: there's also some connection to the 1959 TV show "The Many Loves of Dobie Gillis". And [Hipsterdufus](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Hipsterdufus) is apparently now a thing.

Answer (score 2):

Noun: **Useless Tit**
Adjective:  **Tit-useless**

Often but not always applied to males, probably related to the non-functionality of the male breast.

> Dave is a useless tit.
>
> Dave is tit-useless at anything.

Probably a contraction of "...as useless as tits on a nun/bull/ram/log"

Supporting link: https://www.answerbag.com/q_view/53418

Comment: "Tit" seems to indicate an intentional insult. Am I wrong? If not, I don't think OP wanted that shade of meaning.

Answer (score 1):

A [**sad sack**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sad%20sack) is *a blundering, inept person*.

MW defines it as "US, informal", and says the first known use with this meaning is from 1943. However, [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sad#etymonline_v_22587) says:

> *sad sack* is 1920s, popularized by World War II armed forces
>   (specifically by cartoon character invented by Sgt. George Baker,
>   1942, and published in U.S. Armed Forces magazine "Yank"), probably a
>   euphemistic shortening of common military slang phrase *sad sack of
>   shit*.

The term comes from a military context, a soldier who can't seem to do anything correctly.

The definitions in the Urban Dictionary seem to turn the meaning more toward a depressed or depressing person. But the original context used sad in the sense of pitiful.

Comment: Thanks for finding that!  Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that from my phone.

Comment: I've added the links/detail but you might like to re-edit your middle paragraphs in light of the (slightly duplicated) etymological discussion. :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Inept

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/inept

in·ept  (ĭn-ĕpt′)
adj.
1. Lacking or showing a lack of skill or competence; bungling or clumsy: an inept actor; an inept performance.
2. Showing a lack of judgment, sense, or reason; inappropriate or foolish: an inept remark.

Answer (score 1):

Adding [nincompoop](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nincompoop) as a suggestion.

> A silly or foolish person.

A slightly older word in UK English so not too widely used.

Answer (score 0):

There is a word we use called Nixie. It comes from the German word Nichtse which means a slacker/good-for-nothing. 
The word is very popular among the Pennsylvania Dutch community.

Comment: "The word is very popular among the Pennsylvania Dutch community" - should we infer anything from this? ;-)

Comment: "*Nichtse*" never heard this. Would it perhaps be Dutch?

Comment: A think of a Nixie as [a water spirit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neck_(water_spirit)).

Comment: @alk it’s certainly not Dutch, it does seem to be based on the German ‘nicht’. We do have a word for nothing (niks) which sounds similar though, and a good-for-nothing can be called a niksnut.